# Why do I get None for key for first level in firebase realtime base with nested 2 levels

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, nonetype

I am trying to iter through childs, but I get None for first key which should be e.g. id of case.

[example of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DuJA.png)

[image: example of base]

and this is result of code `[None, {'-MaISrSqXnill-8W7sG1': {'datum': '22.5.2021', 'idtip_uplate': '11', 'iduplata': '1', 'novaca': '50', 'predmet': '1'}}]`

For some reason he don't see first key

Comment: I have found 1 solution, but there is probably better one, until that one found this can help. Everything was working ok until today, same problem. I used integers for keys, but when I put string everything is fine again. Try to put string for paths in firebase when it's nesting, if you write just '4' that will be 4 (int) but if you write "'4'" that will be string and it will work at least it worked for me.

Comment: And later if you want to compare that key with something remove ' key.removeprefix("'") key.removesuffix("'")

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use numeric keys (like the `1`) in your data, you run the risk that Firebase will try to be helpful and interpret those keys as indexes in an array. So in your data it sees it as an array of size 2, with no element at index `0` and the `-M...` element at index `1`. And that's what the output you print shows.

To prevent Firebase from interpreting the keys as an array, ensure they start with a string value. So prefix them with a short known value, like `"key1"`.

For more on this, also see: [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).